# How to map to custom field type by fetching from repository in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

In springboot app I have used `UserDateAudit` class which means whichever entity class extends it, that class automatically has 4 fields populated when they should be `createdBy` `createdAt` `updatedBy` `updatedAt`. The `UserSummary` class contains info about the `User`.  I have an entity `Branch` which extends `UserDateAudit`. Now when I convert `Branch` to `BranchDTO` I also need to have `UserSummary` object to know who created the record. The `Branch` records are saving successfully with the appropriate `user_id` in `createdBy` db column. So I am thinking I would have a custom function in mapper which will take `user_id` from `Branch` then find in Db then create `UserSummary` object and assign to `BRanchDTO`. Is there a proper way to acheive this?

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring")
public interface BranchMapper
{
    Branch toBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO);
    BranchDTO toBranchDTO(Branch branch);
    List<BranchDTO> toBranchDTOS(List<Branch> branches);
    Branch updateBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO, @MappingTarget Branch branch);

}
```

**DateAudit.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true
)
public abstract class DateAudit implements Serializable
{
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant updatedAt;
}
```

**UserDateAudit.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdBy", "updatedBy"},
        allowGetters = true
)
public class UserDateAudit extends DateAudit
{
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long updatedBy;
}
```

**Branch.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branches")
public class Branch extends UserDateAudit
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "default_branch", nullable = false)
    private boolean defaultBranch;
}
```

**BranchDTO.java**

```
public class BranchDTO
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean defaultBranch;
    UserSummary createdBy;
}
```

**UserSummary.java**

```
public class UserSummary
{
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapStruct has the possibility to use other mappers or services via `Mapper#uses`.

Let's imagine that you have a service which looks like the following:

```
public interface UserSummaryService {

    UserSummary getUserSummary(Long userId);

}
```

then in your mapper you can do:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = "spring", uses = UserSummaryService.class)
public interface BranchMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdBy", ignore = true)
    Branch toBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO);

    BranchDTO toBranchDTO(Branch branch);

    List<BranchDTO> toBranchDTOS(List<Branch> branches);

    @InheritConfiguration
    Branch updateBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO, @MappingTarget Branch branch);

}
```

With this mapper when mapping from the `BranchDTO` into `Branch` the `createdBy` will be ignored.

By using `@InheritConfiguration` the `updateBranch` mapping will inherit the configuration from the `toBranch` method and ignore the `createdBy` mapping.

MapStruct will automatically see that there is a mapping method between `Long` and `UserSummary` in the `UserSummaryService` and will invoke it to map the `createdBy` between `Branch` and `BranchDTO` in the `toBranchDTO` method.